# Error when trying to play sound

Tags: android

I tried to build a button that on click plays a sound.

Below is my code. When I click the button I get Error (-19, 0).

What does it mean?

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    MediaPlayer click = MediaPlayer.create(Timer.this, R.raw.click);
        click.start();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Why you use MediaPlayer? Is your sound file have a big size?

Comment: no, it is not, any other way?

Comment: Then, I think, best way use a SoundPull, as answered peple below. But if you need only MediaPlayer try this:
http://www.badprog.com/android-mediaplayer-example-of-playing-sounds
Before play sound you need to prepare your MediaPlayer. And you don't need to create many copies of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use Soundpool for little sounds like a click. Watch this video:
http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=6&number=79

Answer (score 1):

Playing sounds with `MediaPlayer` isn't a good idea. you should consider using the `SoundPool`
take a look at the [SoundPool's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html)

Answer (score 1):

well to do that...its better to make a new folder called raw inside the resource folder and copy the sound clip there. then add the following under onClick if u wanna play sound on click of a button:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Incoming.this, R.raw.abcd); 
ourSong.start(); //where abcd is ur sound file and Incoming is ur java class
```

where u need to define MediaPlayer ourSong; like this:

```
public class Incoming extends Activity{
MediaPlayer ourSong;
```